# Generating invoice from Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, google-sheets-api, google-docs-api

I have a Google spreadsheet in which I record my freelance jobs. I have it set up that each line calculates whether it is paid for. (Payments are pulled from a separate sheet.)

What I would like to do is to generate an invoice, where I would select the customer and I get a listing of all unpaid entries for that customer.

Using a arrayed filter function does the job, but I can't use that as an invoice because I need the total line underneath, and would prefer the table format matching the count of entries.

Is it possible to insert such information into a Google Doc as a table, or within Sheets, to push the lines following an array down?

I thought this would be a simple enough concept but I can't find anything that does the full deal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a SUM row and SUM column to a query in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55513733/adding-a-sum-row-and-sum-column-to-a-query-in-google-sheets)

Comment: It is definitely possible using Apps Script. Can you share an example of the Sheet you are trying to insert into the Doc?

Comment: @Jescanellas Here is the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11GOCiWs_28ietoLimrHwXYV6GGeQaJHxoIApEeQagg8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I see. And which are the fields of the Sheet you would include in the invoice? I think doing it in Sheets instead of Docs would be easier, and also you could export it as PDF.

Comment: @Jescanellas Date, Hours, Description, Subtotal. And obviously, underneath it all, the actual Total styled accordingly.

Comment: @Tedinoz While adding an element to the filtered array would show the total, I can't style that line accordingly as I would had it been entered on its own.

Comment: @Jescanellas Do you have any specific script in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this script. I'm not sure if the final results is what you are looking for. In case it is not, it can be easily modified:

```js
function onEdit(e) {

  //If you change the Customer in the Invoice sheet, it runs the code
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'A1' && e.source.getSheetName() == 'Invoice'){
    var sprsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var invoice = sprsheet.getSheetByName("Invoice");
    var times = sprsheet.getSheetByName("Times");
    
    var in_customer = invoice.getRange("A1").getValue(); //Name you selected in the dropdown menu
    var data = times.getRange("A1:H").getValues(); //All the data from the Time sheet
    
    var total = 0;
    
    //Loops through all the data looking for unpaid subtotals from that customer
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){ 
      
      /*> "i" represents the row, the second number is the column
        > The rows start at 0 since it is the first array position.
        */
      if (in_customer == data[i][2]) {
        
        if (data[i][7] == 'N'){
          
          total += Number(data[i][5]); //Accumulates each subtotal into total
          
          invoice.appendRow([data[i][0], data[i][1], data[i][3], data[i][5]]);
        }
      }
            
    }
    invoice.appendRow(["Total: ","","", total]);
    
  }
}
```

This results in (I changed some values to test it):

[image]

As you see I added some headers.

**References**:

- [Range Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [onEdit Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

Comment: This still requires empty space below where the data will be appended, correct? Or will .appendRow actually insert a row?

Comment: It does physically add rows, for example if you removed all the rows from 4 to 1000, it will still add those new rows from my example.

Comment: Would it push down existing data? I would want it that way so that I can style an invoice with something to go underneath, or to give the table a style that grows or shrinks with it. I would also want the total line to have it's own style.

Comment: It won't push it, it will add it at the end. If you want to add something underneath, you can add it as another `append` after the Total line. Regarding the style, you can use the [setRichTextValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setrichtextvaluevalue) method using something like `invoice.getRange(...).setRichTextValue(richtext)`. More info about setting richText [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess I can add a line to first clear the sheet (past the customer box) upon switching customers.